# Nodejs fs module: How to readFile and create json object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am reading below data from file now i want to create json object from it,how can i create that using nodejs fs module ?

app.js

```
var path = "./ditLogs/" + file;
                fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
                   console.log('reading file data', data.toString());
                });
```

Here is data in file that i need to create json for

file.txt

```
{"event":"test data"}
{"event":"test data"}
{"event":"test data"}
```

Comment: `.split("\n").map(a=>JSON.parse(a))`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample function:

```
function(strFromFile) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(strFromFile);
  } catch(e) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**FS Module**

While developing in NodeJS the need to access a computer's file system is sometimes necessary.  FS Module is a utility that assists with this process.

FS includes some functions that allow for different activities to be done on the file system via a wrapper around the API.

This should be included/required/imported into any JS that needs to interact with the file system API.

```
var fs = require("fs");
```

These are the different methods you can use on this API which are all asynchronous:

fs.readFile {fs.readFile('input.txt', function(err, data)

```
// Asynchronous read
fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
});
```

fs.writeFile

```
fs.writeFile('input.txt', 'Simply Easy Learning!',  function(err) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }

   console.log("Data written successfully!");
   console.log("Let's read newly written data");
   fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
         return console.error(err);
      }
      console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
   });
});
```

open

```
// Asynchronous - Opening File
console.log("Going to open file!");
fs.open('input.txt', 'r+', function(err, fd) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
  console.log("File opened successfully!");    
});
```

fs.stat (provides information about the file) e.g.

```
fs.stat('input.txt', function (err, stats) {
   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log(stats);
   console.log("Got file info successfully!");

   // Check file type
   console.log("isFile ? " + stats.isFile());
   console.log("isDirectory ? " + stats.isDirectory());   
});
```

fs.read (similar to readFile and should not be the first choice for reading a file)

fs.close

```
// Close the opened file.
fs.close(fd, function(err){
  if (err){
     console.log(err);
  }
     console.log("File closed successfully.");
});
```

ftruncate (truncate an opened file)

unlink (delete an opened file)

```
fs.unlink('input.txt', function(err) {
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("File deleted successfully!");
});
```

fs.mkdir (make new directory)

```
fs.mkdir('/tmp/test',function(err){
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

fs.readdir (reads a directory)

```
fs.readdir("/tmp/",function(err, files){
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   files.forEach( function (file){
      console.log( file );
   });
});
```

fs.rmdir (remove directory)

```
fs.rmdir("/tmp/test",function(err){
   if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("Going to read directory /tmp");

   fs.readdir("/tmp/",function(err, files){
      if (err) {
         return console.error(err);
      }
      files.forEach( function (file){
         console.log( file );
      });
   });
});
```

Synchronous functions:

readFileSync

```
// Synchronous read
var data = fs.readFileSync('input.txt');
console.log("Synchronous read: " + data.toString());
```

writeFileSync

```
// Synchronous write
var data = fs.writeFileSync('input.txt', 'asdasdasd');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply read using line-by-line package, less headache, more control on reading process (it can pause, resume reading, close file descriptor ondemand, skip N lines) with less code.

1) install:

```
npm i --save line-by-line
npm i --save lodash
```

2) implement

```
var lineByLine = require('line-by-line'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    path = require('path');


var lines = [];
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "ditLogs", file);
var fileReader = new lineByLine(filePath);

fileReader.on('line', function(line) {
  line = JSON.parse(line);
  if(_.isPlainObject(line) && !_.isEmpty(line)) {
    lines.push(line);
  }

  // optional
  doSomethingWithLine(line);
});

function doSomethingWithLine(line) {
  // for example You can save to db or send to somewhere using request libary or just show in console
}

fileReader.on('error', function(error) {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(-1);
});

fileReader.on('end', function() {
  doSomethingAfterParsingAllLines(lines);
});

function doSomethingAfterParsingAllLines(records) {
  // do something with data
}
```

Comment: some wise guy downvoted my answer without saying why. not fair! (:

Answer (score -1):

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('student.json');  
let student = JSON.parse(rawdata);  
console.log(student);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what is new in your answer? There are other existing answers which explain the same better.